# Discord.js get user connections as bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Hey I'm trying to make a bot that will check user's connected battle.net account and load game rank. I'm using *discord.js* library and trying to acccess *UserProfile* via bot, which isn't allowed since you can't *.fetchProfile()*. Based on discord.js I'm only allowed to check *UserProfile* and then *connections* this way.
My question is: is there any way for bot to load user's connected accounts ? I only need battle.net tag that user verified and connected to discord account.

User: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User

UserProfile: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserProfile

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible when using a "real" bot account, however it is possible if you're using a user bot account.

I'd suggest a workaround of using OAuth2. You could have users authenticate your bot with OAuth2, and then fetch their connections this way. Some more information at https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2

Comment: Thanks for answer, yea I did a workaround and used normal user account as bot, hopefully the account won't get banned for using it on small server :D

Answer (score -1):

I think I might have a way to get close to that. It took me a while, but I think I've figured out how you can check if someone (in my case, just the bot itself) is playing a certain game. You could probably replace client.user with the user you want to check. Here's the code:

```
if (client.user.presence.game.name == "INSERT GAME TO LOOK FOR HERE") {  
    ACTION TO BE CARRIED OUT
}
```