# discord.py | Access user's connections via an individual OAuth link

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

Excuse me if I missed something and this is a duplicate, other QA's still left me with some questions.

I wanted to see if it was possible for my bot to access user connections (Steam acc, Reddit, etc.) so that the user can use a command to enable notifications in a specific channel, so that it would promote when they publish a video.

I've found similar bots, but they all required manual entering and they were admin-only.

---

I've found that it is NOT possible to directly access them (and rightfully so):

> Unfortunately this is not possible when using a "real" bot account, however it is possible if you're using a user bot account.
>
> I'd suggest a workaround of using OAuth2. You could have users authenticate your bot with OAuth2, and then fetch their connections this way. Some more information at [`https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2`](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2)

(Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44265167/16255372)

But that last statement about OAuth really got me wondering.

If it is required for each user to authenticate via a link, that is an acceptable compromise for me.

On the discord developers website, I've found a `connections` scope which would allow the bot to access the connections of the user that authenticated via the link.

I also found a url for getting the user's connections [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user-connections)

> #### Get User Connections
>
> *GET* `/users/@me/connections`
>
> Returns a list of connection objects. Requires the connections OAuth2 scope.

But on other sources, I've seen that the scope is inaccessible to bots.

Furthermore, I don't see connections accessible in discord.py, which is what I use.

So my question is + TL;DR:

1. Is it possible to access the user's connections, even if they each have to click on an oauth link
   (connections scope)
2. Would this be possible using discord.py?
   (potentially using `discord.ClientUser`?)

---

Thank you for reading, I am also a new contributor. If you feel that I missed something or could elaborate or explain things better, please let me know how I could improve my question.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is it possible to access the user's connections, even if they each have to click on an oauth link (connections scope)

YES (only possible using OAuth).

> Would this be possible using discord.py? (potentially using discord.ClientUser?)

Unfortunately, no. Discord.PY does not support OAuth. You would have to do it yourself by creating a Web Application etc.